# Golang: How to use same the method for different structures

Tags: go, interface

How can I apply the same logic to different structures?

For example, update a struct's field.
I want to share the same `UpdateName` logic for both struct A and B

A and B are from different packages.

```golang
// model/A.go
type A struct {
   name  string
   total int64
   date  time.Time
}
```

```golang
// model/B.go
type B struct {
   name  string
   price float64
   total int64
   date  time.Time
}
```

Hopefully combine duplicated logic as one.

```golang
// service/a.go
func UpdateName(data *A) {
   data.Name = "NEW"
}

// service/b.go
func UpdateName(data *B) {
   data.Name = "NEW"
}
```

I'd like to use an interface for decoupling.
Furthermore, How can I parse interface as a parameter.

```golang
type DataSetter() interface {
    SetName(name string)
    SetTotal(total int64)
}
```

Thanks for helping me with this basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple value assignments like you showed, it is often better to simply expose the field:

```
type A struct {
   Name string
   ...
}

...
func f(a *A) {
   a.Name="x"
}
```

You might consider embedding a common struct:

```
type Common struct {
   Name string
}

func (c *Common) SetName(s string) {
   c.Name=s
}


type A struct {
   Common
   ...
}

type B struct {
   Common
   ...
}

func f(a *A) {
   a.SetName("x")
}
```

You can use an interface that represents the functions of the common type:

```
type WithName interface {
   SetName(string)
}


func f(x WithName) {
   x.SetName("x")
}


func g(a *A) {
   f(a)
}

func h(b *B) {
   f(b)
}
```

But you wouldn't want to do this for just `SetName`.